# Bash Script: No such file or directory when defining variable via source vars.txt

Tags: bash, shell, sed, scripting, centos

I have a script that creates a hash of a file, writes it to vars.txt and then checks that variable next time the script is run to determine if the file has changed.

[Here is the script](http://pastebin.com/QQGHGBKR) and  [vars.txt](http://pastebin.com/WJgwVdkt) (pastebin)

When I run the script I call the variable with `source /path/to/file`

This now gives me the following error when the file is parsed:

```
/opt/scripts/AutoCommit/vars.txt: line 2: etchttpdconf_dvhost.conf=925ec4d7bd0dc94c3710bcf5fb2c80f422806bb5  /etc/httpd/conf.d/vhost.conf: No such file or directory
```

On top of that, when the file changes `sed` is now not replacing the line but adding an additional line underneath. It had not done this in the past.

You get a file that ends up [like this.](http://pastebin.com/1Nv9hdss) Until recently this did not happen so I suspect they are both caused by the same issue.

[Here is a stripped down version of the script, where I believe the problem may be.](http://pastebin.com/R7ZECL2K)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Problem seems to be that your filename contains *multiple* dots. When generating the variable name, only the first one is replaced by an underscore. Having a dot in a variable name results in the cryptic error message you get, but actually is just a syntax error.

To substitute all occurances of a pattern in Bash's "parameter expansion" you have to prepend a `/` to the pattern. So the fix for your problem is to use the following code in line 6 of your script:

```
fileVarName="${fileVarName//./_}"
```